# jQuery - Get values from jQuery array got from field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

First I have one field with `daterangepicker`.

I get value using `$("#field").val()`.

I got like

```
{"start":"2018-03-23","end":"2018-03-29"}
```

But, I need start date and end date value from

```
{"start":"2018-03-23","end":"2018-03-29"}
```

My code is

```
<input id="field" type="text" value='' /><br/>
```

```
$(function() {
  'use strict';
   $("#field").daterangepicker({
       dateFormat:'dd M',
       datepickerOptions : {
        numberOfMonths : 2
     }
   });
   var curnt = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
  var weeks = moment().subtract('days', 6).startOf('day').toDate();
  $("#field").daterangepicker("setRange", {start: weeks, end: curnt});
 });

function get_graph_data(){

  var dates = JSON.parse($("#field").val());
  console.log(dates.start);
  console.log(dates.end);

  var data = {
    'action'  : 'example_ajax_request',
    'wp_graph': $("#field").val()
  };

  jQuery.post(ajax_url, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your got like and need like both are same - `{"start":"2018-03-23","end":"2018-03-29"}` What's the difference?

Comment: If there's a `.setRange()` then there will (most likely) also be a `.getRange()`.

Comment: Always add a link to the library you're using (or even better a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `daterangepicker` plugin so you should use it's methods instead of jQuery's `val()`. Select an input field and call `data('daterangepicker')`. Returned object contains `startDate` and `endDate` objects. Keep in mind that they are Date objects (not Strings), so you will need to format if you want to print them.

```js
$('#field').daterangepicker({
  locale: {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  },
  startDate: '2018-01-01',
  endDate: '2018-12-31'
});

$("#getDateRange").click(function() {
  var data = $("#field").data('daterangepicker');
  var startDate = data.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var endDate = data.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  alert('Start date: ' + startDate + ', end date: ' + endDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input id="field" type="text" value='' />
<button type="button" id="getDateRange">Get start date</button>
```

It's always a good habit to check out official documentation of a plugin. You can check it out [here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/).

Comment: Getting error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDate' of undefined**

Comment: Thanks! It is working fine.But, i integrate in my website it not working.

Answer (score 1):

What you get from the `$("#field").val()` is a JSON. You can easily do something like:

```
var dates = JSON.parse($("#field").val());
dates.start; // "2018-03-23"
dates.end;   // "2018-03-29"
```

A snippet to help you:

```js
$(function () {
  var dates = JSON.parse($("#field").val());
  console.log(dates.start); // "2018-03-23"
  console.log(dates.end);   // "2018-03-29"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" type="hidden" value='{"start":"2018-03-23","end":"2018-03-29"}' />
```

Comment: @MilanHirpara Tell me one thing. Clicking on Run code snippet works for you? If it does, let's debug your code.

Comment: @MilanHirpara Dude, wait. I just showed that for your reference. What you need to copy is `var dates = JSON.parse($("#field").val());
dates.start; // "2018-03-23"
dates.end;   // "2018-03-29"`

Comment: @MilanHirpara Can you show me your full code so that I can completely solve it.

Comment: @MilanHirpara Can you make a [mcve] please? Something that's working... Which plugin have you used?